# how to get ontouch event in bitmap inside canvas?

Tags: android

i have a bitmap inside a canvas.the class implements ontouchlistener.i need to hide the image while touch on the image.

```
class Panel extends View implements View.OnTouchListener {
Paint linepaint=new Paint();

  public Panel(Context context) {
    super(context);
  }
 @Override
 public void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    Bitmap imgtable = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.table_01);
    canvas.drawBitmap(imgtable, centrex, centrey, null);
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
 }

}
```

Comment: how to type '<' sign in emulator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make on touch listener for the view where you draw the image. And there change the visibility of the view. Not in onDraw();

Edit:

If you set the `Bitmap` image for example on a `ImageView`, then `onTouchListener()` must be applied on the ImageView. Bitmap image is only a data that is supplied to the view(s).

Comment: i am sorry,i can't get what you mean.

Comment: If you set the Bitmap image for example on a `ImageView`, then `onTouchListener()` must be applied `on the ImageView`. Bitmap image is only a data that is supplied to the view(s).